# Excel: Best way to refresh Excel tables from SQL Server and in the Cloud?

Tags: sql-server, excel, sharepoint, office365

I have an Excel workbook that has two worksheets. Each worksheet has a table reference that I use in a `PowerQuery`, to connect to a `SQL Server` database.

Users are able to RIGHT-CLICK -> REFRESH each table and update the data from SQL Server.

I want to be able to place this workbook in `Sharepoint Online (Office 365)`, so more than one person can open it, at the same time, and get the same data - also at the same time.

Is all this possible please?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `Connection Properties` found under `Data` -> `Refresh All`? From there you can set up automatic refreshes based on a time interval/upon opening the file.

Comment: @StevenPomponio thanks, but will that fire up on its own once the workbook is in sharepoint?

Comment: According to [Office support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/refreshing-data-in-a-workbook-in-a-browser-window-89560193-0c11-420b-b7d8-744766ccdc94) about data refresh within Sharepoint:  
"*Depending on how your environment is configured, data refresh might not occur. For example, if someone created a workbook that uses secure, external data connections to on-premises servers, those data connections will probably not work in Microsoft 365. If you run into a situation where you can’t refresh the data in a browser window, try opening the workbook in Excel.*"

Comment: I ran a test instance in where I created an Excel document and placed a `PowerQuery` in it and modified the settings to refresh upon open (*however I linked it to a separate Excel file not `SQL Server`*). After uploading it into Sharepoint I closed it out, modified the linked excel file, saved said file and reopened the `PowerQuery` file from Sharepoint (*non-web browser*) and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @StevenPomponio hey thanks for your time and efforts. Yes I can do the same, but only if both the PowerQuery workbook and the source workbook are both in Sharepoint. I tried both data sources (SQL and Excel) on our on-prem location and the Sharepoint workbook did a refresh, but no data had changed. I am surprised it didn't come back with a "cannot connect" error or something.